# Tailwindcss overiding already existing HTML components (h1,h2,h3...) sizes on both Web and mobile

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS with Next.js on a project, I want to check how can I override the `h1` font size from 40px to 46px for example on Desktop (1440px) and override again its font size from 40px to 30px on mobile web (375px).

I have tried adding a new property in the `tailwindcss.config` file

```
fontSize: {
  h1: '46px',
  h2: '40px',
},
```

But I can't find a way to do it on mobile.

I used to do it in a normal css file the below way

```
h1{
  font-size:46px
}
```

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  h1{
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#tailwind) you should add these styles in the base layer in your global style file
it should look something like this

```
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply text-3xl lg:text-5xl;
  }
}
```

Since by default, Tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system, i have added the size for mobile and the breakpoint for large screen after [(you can add your custom breakpoints in the tailwind.config file if you want)](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-your-theme)